# Force re-evaluation of maxima variable

Tags: maxima

This may be super simple but I cannot find a way to get Maxima to tell me that c is now 8, not 3? Can anyone help?

```
(%i1) a:1;
(%o1)                                  1
(%i2) b:2;
(%o2)                                  2
(%i3) c:a+b;
(%o3)                                  3
(%i4) ''c;
(%o4)                                  3
(%i5) a:6;
(%o5)                                  6
(%i6) ''c;
(%o6)                                  3
```

Many thanks
Tom

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to define include a [*prevent evaluation* (')](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_8.html) operator in the definition of`c`. For example:

```
(%i1) c : '(a+b);
(%o1)                                                       b + a
(%i2) a:1;
(%o2)                                                         1
(%i3) b:2;
(%o3)                                                         2
(%i4) ''c;
(%o4)                                                         3
(%i5) a:6;
(%o5)                                                         6
(%i6) ''c;
(%o6)                                                         8
```

Note that you can also post-fix the values of `a` and `b`:

```
(%i7) c, a:11, b:5;
(%o7)                                                         16
```

Comment: Pretty much agreed, although I would write `c : '(a + b)` in the first line since in `c : 'a + b`, the variable `b` is not quoted.

Comment: @RobertDodier: Thank you for the correction. Feel free to make an edit next time :-).

Comment: @Thor Thanks for that. It may sound odd but is there a global setting to prevent evaluation? ie set ' for all expressions?

Comment: @TomH: not that I am aware of, but I am not a Maxima expert.